# Set value of key while iterating through object

Tags: javascript

What would I put in the for loop to have the console spit out "Amy"?

```
var inputs = {Name:null};

for (input in inputs) {
    XXXXX = "Amy";
}

console.log(inputs.Name);
```

I've tried these to no avail so it feels like I'm missing something:

```
input = "Amy";
inputs.input = "Amy";
inputs[input] = "Amy";
```

Is it that the 'input' iterator is a reference, while I'm trying to use it as a variable? I'm also trying not to use Object.keys()

Comment: `inputs[input] = "Amy";`, in your code already, will do the trick.

Comment: basics of js will do the trick

Comment: What's wrong with the code above: running all three "Amy" lines means `input = "Amy";` changes the key to `"Amy"` which causes `inputs[input] = "Amy";` to return `null` for referencing the key `"Name"`. Don't do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you didn't try `inputs[input] = "Amy";` because that works:

```js
var inputs = {Name:null};

for (var input in inputs) {
    inputs[input] = "Amy";
}

console.log(inputs.Name);
```